# swift nested dictionary sorted result error

Tags: swift, sorting, dictionary

the below source code results error like this:

**"cannot assign value of type '[Dictionary<Int, Double>.Element]' (aka 'Array<(key: Int, value: Double)>') to type '[Int : Double]?'
dateAndDict[date] = sortedDict"**

Well, basically, what I am trying to do is sorting the nested Dictionary by Value.

source code:

```
let date = Date()
var dict = [2:4.0, 4:12.0 ,6:3.0,7:45.0, 8:15.0]

var dateAndDict:[Date:[Int:Double]]


let sortedDict = dict.sorted { currentElement , nextElement in
    
    return currentElement.value < nextElement.value
}


dateAndDict[date] = sortedDict
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot sort a dictionary. A dictionary is unordered by definition. The result of calling `sorted` on a dictionary is an **array** of tuples which the error clearly states (`aka Array<(key: Int, value: Double)>`)

Comment: Thanks to @vadian.  "var dateAndDict:[Date:[Int:Double]]" is corrected as "var dateAndDict:[Date:[(key: Int, value: Double)]] = [:]"